How to get State Space representation from Jacobian of a non-linear system?
I have a non-linear system that is described by these equations:
$$\dot{x_1} = \frac{60}{x_2}*(-k_2*\frac{R*T}{V}*\frac{x_2}{k_1}*x_1 +k_2*\frac{R*T}{V}*k_3*u_1)$$
$$\dot{x_2} = \frac{60}{\frac{J*x_2}{(\frac{30}{\pi})}}*(x1*(\theta - 1)*\mu_\delta-u_2);$$
The steady state occurs when $x2=800$, $u1=3.1145$, $u2=31.15$ and $k_1=3961$, $k_2=102$, $k_3=2.02$, $\frac{RT}{V} = 0.075$, $\frac{J}{\frac{30}{\pi}}=0.027$.
State vectors are:
$$x = \begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$u = \begin{pmatrix}
u_1\\
u_2\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
I've calculated the Jacobian matrices to linearize the system:
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial\dot{x_1}}{\partial x_1}&\frac{\partial\dot{x_1}}{\partial x_2}\\
\frac{\partial\dot{x_2}}{\partial x_1}&\frac{\partial\dot{x_2}}{\partial x_2}\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$B = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial\dot{x_1}}{\partial u_1}&\frac{\partial\dot{x_1}}{\partial u_2}\\
\frac{\partial\dot{x_2}}{\partial u_1}&\frac{\partial\dot{x_2}}{\partial u_2}\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
The state-space representation of the system is:
$$\Delta x = A \Delta x + B \Delta u$$
$$y = C \Delta x + D \Delta u$$
where
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
-1.545&0\\
0&-1.545\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
572.3\\
-37.04\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$C=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$D=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
I need to get from Jacobian matrices to the state space representation while knowing the the correct numerical result. What are the steps that I am missing in between? Thank you.
